# How to set array response in api-doc?

Tags: api-doc

I tried to generate a API document by [apidoc](http://apidocjs.com/)

If my response is a array like

```
[
   {"id" : 1, "name" : "John"},
   {"id" : 2, "name" : "Mary"}
]
```

How could I set in @apiSuccess?

I had try Object[] but did not know how to set the field name.
Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Lets say in the above example the id and name are of a user-profile, and you have an array of user-profile objects, then the @apiSuccess will look like:

```
/**
 * @api {get} /users
 * @apiSuccess {Object[]} profiles       List of user profiles.
 * @apiSuccess {Number}   profiles.Id    Users id.
 * @apiSuccess {String}   profiles.Name  Users Name.
 */
```